# Set as default merge branch

Tags: git

I have a `master` branch which I always merge with `development`. Is it possible to set `development` as the default merge branch? (To save a few types). Instead of typing:

```
$ (master) git merge development
```

I would just have to

```
$ (master) git merge
```

Comment: You can do `git merge dev<TAB>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible using `git` options.

An option to consider would be to use a workaround, defining an alias for your shell like

```
alias 'gitmd'='git merge dev'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not something you want to do, but you *could* set you local development branch to be upstream to master

```
git branch -u development master
```

And then set upstream to be default merge

```
git config merge.defaultToUpstream true
```

Then `git merge` on master will do what you want. Please note, however, that the branch command above will also change the meaning of push and pull.